# Custom fields in Joomla (similar to those that Wordpress has)

Tags: joomla, field

is there a way to add custom fields (that would be working similarly to those Wordpress has) to Joomla 1.5? I need to be able to have them entered separately from the article content (preferably as input fields next to article title) and also have them available while calling for section/category display.

For example, if any given article has a custom field named 'foo' filled with value 'bar', I need to be able to display it not only wihtin the article, but also on the category page next to the article excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

Any number of CCK style components would allow you to do what you are looking for. Take a look at these - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction

Personally, I use K2 on every Joomla site I do. Once you learn how to use the subtemplates and overrides the extra fields are a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using tags?

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_To_Use_Content_Tags_in_Joomla!

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/joomla-31-tags/

It's flexible and built-in to Joomla, so if it's a good fit for your project it saves installing an extra extension.

Good luck!